# Kendo UI template issue

Tags: kendo-ui

I would like to do sth like this http://jsfiddle.net/kfEfw/115/
but in the kendo.template( .... ) I want to check a variable's value.
In the specific example it doesn't recognize x variable and I would like
to know if there is a way to pass x in the template.

```
var temp = 0; //i want to pass this variable in the template and check it's value
/if temp = 0 I need to render sth and if temp has other value I want to render sth else
window.kendouiTemplate = kendo.template("<div><h1 class='header'><#= data.header#></h1><ul
class='list'><# for (var i = 0, l = data.list.length; i < l; i++) {
#><#if(data.list[i]%2==0){#><li class='item'><#= data.list[i] #></li><#}#><# } #></ul>
</div>", {useWithBlock:false});
```

Thanks in advance,
Artemis

Comment: May I suggest giving the question more specific title? It'd help other people who might have the same issue find your question.

Answer (score 0):

See the demo here --> http://demos.kendoui.com/web/templates/index.html

so in [your case](http://jsfiddle.net/blackjim/kfEfw/116/)

HTML

```
<div id="results"></div>

<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="template">
    <div>
        <h1 class='header'><#= data.header #></h1>
        <h2 class='header2'><#= data.header2 #></h2>
        <h3 class='header3'><#= data.header3 #></h3>
        <h4 class='header4'><#= data.header4 #></h4>
        <h5 class='header5'><#= data.header5 #></h5>
        <h6 class='header6'><#= data.header6 #></h6>
        <ul class='list'>
            <# for (var i=0 , l=data.list.length; i < l; i++) { #>
                <#if(data.list[i]%2==0){#>
                    <li class='item'>
                        <#=data.list[i] #>
                    </li>
                    <#}#>
            <# } #>
        </ul>
    </div>    
</script>
```

JavaScript

```
window.sharedVariables = {
    header: "Header",
    header2: "Header2",
    header3: "Header3",
    header4: "Header4",
    header5: "Header5",
    header6: "Header6",
    list: ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10']
};
var temp = 0; //i want to pass this variable in the template and check it's value
var template = kendo.template($("#template").html()); // your kendo template

function preview() {
    $("#results").html(template(sharedVariables));
}

preview();
```